# Archive Post Not Showing All Post

Tags: custom-post-types

I want to display all my posts but the archive.php page doesn't show any posts, I have a custom post type named car[![enter image description here][1]][1]. The contents of the custom type car showing post.

archive.php

```
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <div class="dealoop">
          <!-- Thumbnail -->
          <div class="loth">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>  
          </div>
          <!-- Thumbnail -->
          <!-- Meta + Excerpt -->
          <div class="mexc">
            <span class="pub"><strong>Tanggal</strong> : <?php the_time('j M Y'); ?> | <strong>Kategori</strong> : <?php echo get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'category', ' ', ' , '); ?></span>
            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
            <div class="dealexc">
             <?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 40, '...' ); ?>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Meta + Excerpt -->
        </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <!-- Archive -->
```

[1]:

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Have you declared this parameter `'has_archive' => true`  in your function where you created this custom post type if not then do this first and then check, hope it's working for you,